# How do you know if you have found all the irreducible representations?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I have come across several problems that are along the lines of ‘find all irreducible representations of...’.  I can find the representations of the group however I don’t know how to go about showing there are no more.

Comment: If the group is finite then (1) the number of non-isomorphic irreducible representations equals the number of conjugacy classes of elements in the group, and (2) the sum of the squares of the dimensions of the irreducible representations equals the order of the group. Either of these facts can be used to show that your list is complete.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly reasonable question. Would the downvoter care to comment/give some constructive criticism?